# Faster way to parse file to array, compare to array in second file

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I currently have an MGF file containing MS2 spectral data (QE_2706_229_sequest_high_conf.mgf). The file template is in the link below, as well as a snippet of example:

http://www.matrixscience.com/help/data_file_help.html

```
BEGIN IONS
TITLE=File3249 Spectrum10594 scans: 11084
PEPMASS=499.59366 927079.3
CHARGE=3+
RTINSECONDS=1710
SCANS=11084
104.053180 3866.360000
110.071530 178805.000000
111.068610 1869.210000
111.074780 10738.600000
112.087240 13117.900000
113.071150 7148.790000
114.102690 4146.490000
115.086840 11835.600000
116.070850 6230.980000
... ...
END IONS
```

This unannotated spectral file contains thousands of these entries, the total file size is ~150 MB.
I then have a series of text files which I need to parse. Each file is similar to the format above, with the first column being read into a numpy array. Then the unannotated spectra file is parsed for each entry until a matching array is found from the annotated text files input.

(Filename GRPGPVAGHHQMPR)

```
       m/z            i matches
 104.05318      3866.4
 110.07153    178805.4
 111.06861      1869.2
 111.07478     10738.6
 112.08724     13117.9
 113.07115      7148.8
 114.10269      4146.5
 115.08684     11835.6
 116.07085      6231.0
```

Once a match is found, an MGF annotated file is written that then contains the full entry information in the unannotated file, but with a line that specifies the filename of the annotated text file that matched that particular entry. The output is below:

```
BEGIN IONS
SEQ=GRPGPVAGHHQMPR
TITLE=File3249 Spectrum10594 scans: 11084
PEPMASS=499.59366 927079.3
... ...
END IONS
```

There may be a much more computationally inexpensive way to parse. Given 2,000 annotated files to search through, with the above large unannotated file, parsing currently takes ~ 12 hrs on a 2.6 GHz quad-core Intel Haswell cpu.

Here is the below working code:

```
import numpy as np
import sys
from pyteomics import mgf
from glob import glob

def main():
    """
    Usage: python mgf_parser
    """

    pep_files = glob('*.txt')
    mgf_file = 'QE_2706_229_sequest_high_conf.mgf'
    process(mgf_file, pep_files)

def process(mgf_file, pep_files):
    """Parses spectra from annotated text file. Converts m/z values to numpy array.

        If spectra array matches entry in MGF file, writes annotated MGF file.
    """

    ann_arrays = {}
    for ann_spectra in pep_files:
        a = np.genfromtxt(ann_spectra, dtype=float, invalid_raise=False, 
                          usemask=False, filling_values=0.0, usecols=(0))              
        b = np.delete(a, 0)
        ann_arrays[ann_spectra] = b

    with mgf.read(mgf_file) as reader:
        for spectrum in reader:
            for ann_spectra, array in ann_arrays.iteritems():       
                if np.array_equal(array, spectrum['m/z array']):
                    print '> Spectral match found for file {}.txt'.format(ann_spectra[:-4])
                    file_name = '{}.mgf'.format(ann_spectra[:-4])
                    spectrum['params']['seq'] = file_name[52:file_name.find('-') - 1]
                    mgf.write((spectrum,), file_name)        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This was used to be able to only parse a given number of files at a time. Suggestions on any more efficient parsing methods?

Comment: You say that you run this on a quad-core processor but it seems to me that neither `threading` nor `multiprocessing` is implemented anywhere. It seems to me that you could do so fairly easily with one of the `for` loops in the function `process`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see room for improvement in the fact that you are parsing the whole MGF file repeatedly for each of the small files. If you refactor the code so that it is only parsed once, you may get a decent speedup.

Here's how I would tweak your code, simultaneously getting rid of the bash loop, and also using the [`mgf.write`](https://pyteomics.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mgf.html#pyteomics.mgf.write) function, which is probably a bit slower than `np.savetxt`, but easier to use:

```
from pyteomics import mgf
import sys
import numpy as np

def process(mgf_file, pep_files):
    ann_arrays = {}
    for ann_spectra in pep_files:
        a = np.genfromtxt(ann_spectra, invalid_raise=False,
                          filling_values=0.0, usecols=(0,))              
        b = np.delete(a, 0)
        ann_arrays[ann_spectra] = b

    with mgf.read(mgf_file) as reader:
        for spectrum in reader:
            for ann_spectra, array in ann_arrays.iteritems():
                if np.allclose(array, spectrum['m/z array']):
                # allclose may be better for floats than array_equal
                    file_name = 'DeNovo/good_training_seq/{}.mgf'.format(
                                                      ann_spectra[:-4])
                    spectrum['params']['seq'] = ann_spectra[
                                                      :ann_spectra.find('-') - 1]
                    mgf.write((spectrum,), file_name)    

if __name__ == '__main__':
     pep_files = sys.argv[1:]
     mgf_file = '/DeNovo/QE_2706_229_sequest_high_conf.mgf'
     process(mgf_file, pep_files)
```

Then to achieve the same as your bash loop did, you would call it as

```
python2.7 mgf_parser.py *.txt
```

If the expanded argument list is too long, you can use [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) instead of relying on bash to expand it:

```
from glob import iglob
pep_files = iglob(sys.argv[1])
```

And call it like this to prevent expansion by bash:

```
python2.7 mgf_parser.py '*.txt'
```

Comment: The code has been updated with the suggested changes. It runs correctly with correct output running from bash calling the script (not shown), but the above version when run without the bash loop just writes 7 (correct) annotated mgf files, then writes to files 2-6 again repeatedly.

Comment: @user2277435 I'm not sure I understand the difference between desired and actual behavior, could you please elaborate?

Comment: I have thousands of unannotated spectra in text files. These spectra need to be matched to the corresponding entry in the mgf file, and an annotated mgf file produced *for each unannotated text file*. As of now, the above version fails with only correctly matching the first few spectra, writing the same files over and over again.

Comment: @user2277435 The "suggested" code in your question is different from my answer: see the indentation level of the `with mgf.read(...)` block. Is that a typo?

Comment: @LevLivitsky That was the issue, I see correct output now. Parsing is orders of magnitude faster. Many thanks.

Comment: @LevLivisky Now that I can parse 10,000 of spectra, I'm getting an: '-bash: /opt/local/bin/python2.7: Argument list too long' error when parsing 30,000 plus. A cursory look shows this is OS dependent for bash, any ideas to be able to run the entire dataset at once?

Comment: @user2277435 I added a suggestion at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: @LevLivitsky '*.txt' throws an IOError for the numpy _genfromtxt_ method. Glob, however, works for the larger dataset.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57408/discussion-between-user2277435-and-lev-levitsky).

Comment: Well, I replied in chat @user2277435